# Swift - Same set of gestures on multiple views

Tags: ios, swift3, gesture

I have 3 Gestures that need to play well with each other... across many different views. The Gestures are Pan / Pinch / Rotate. I say 'many different views' because there's several buttons in my UI that create shapes (views). Each of these views should be able to perform the above 3 gestures.

The problem I am facing is the gestures only properly work on the most recent shape (view) that got added. If I add 1 shape, rotate and move it, then add shape 2, shape 1 is now "locked" and can't be interacted with. (however shape 2 *can* be interacted with.)

My code is below:

```
var panRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer!
var pinchRecognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer!
var rotateRecognizer:UIRotationGestureRecognizer!
```

viewDidLoad:

```
    panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.draggedView(_:)))
    pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pinchedView(_:)))
    rotateRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.rotatedView(_:)))
    panRecognizer.delegate = self
    pinchRecognizer.delegate = self
    rotateRecognizer.delegate = self
    shapeView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    shapeView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
```

Add shape button:

```
    // some code comprising the shapes. not relevant to issue
    shapeView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
    shapeView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)
    shapeView.addGestureRecognizer(rotateRecognizer)
    shapeView.backgroundColor=UIColor.green

    self.mainView.addSubview(shapeView)
```

The methods the gestures

```
func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x:(sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x, y:(sender.view?.center.y)! + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
func pinchedView(_ sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    sender.view?.transform = (sender.view?.transform)!.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
    sender.scale = 1.0
}
func rotatedView(_ recognizer:UIRotationGestureRecognizer){
    shapeView.transform = recognizer.view!.transform.rotated(by: recognizer.rotation)
    recognizer.rotation = 0
}
```

**So to re-cap...**
The above code works just fine, however it limits me to performing gestures on only the last / newest shape that was added. I need to be able to do this to every single shape that gets added with the 'Add Shape' button.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. Easily enough, all I had to do was subclass UIView. I added all of the gesture recognizers in layoutSubviews(). In the Main VC, I just create an instance of the subclass, instead of UIView. This allows all of the shapes to be controlled independently.